# Can't get PHP to connect to MySQL

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, lamp

Having to set up a server from scratch and install PHP & MySQL, running into an issue getting PHP to connect to MySQL. I can successfully connect to the database via command line, but when I try to do it through PHP I get this error:

```
#2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)
```

The mysql server is running and can be connected to via command line. The .sock file is in the correct path and is chmod 777 so it can be connected to by any user.

Running PHP Version 5.2.14. MySQL Client API version 5.0.90, MySQL version 5.1.50

Using phpMyAdmin to connect, and have tried tcp and socket type connections. All give the same error.

Comment: What distribution? do you have the php-mysql package installed for it?

Comment: Yes I do, php-mysql-5.2.14-2.el5.art

Comment: Wow. Ok so I found it. Talk about strange problem. Saw in the system logs "SELinux is preventing the http daemon from connecting to network port 3306 For complete SELinux messages." so I disabled SeLinux (whatever the hell that is) and it appears to be working now. Good ol logs save the day.

Answer (score 0):

rpm -qa|grep -i php-mysql check that out

Comment: php-mysql-5.2.14-2.el5.art

Comment: vi /var/www/html/info.php <?php
phpinfo();
?> http://192.168.0.100/info.php look for mysql support in php page

Comment: PHP is compiled with the MySQL module, Client API version 5.0.90

Comment: yum remove mysql mysql-server then install using yum install mysql mysql-server

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?35,64808,76338#msg-76338 one more link i could found which may help you!!

Comment: It must be something with the actual base install because can't connect through regluar php either mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","XXX");

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure phpmyadmin to access you server.

Read [faq 2.2 and 2.3](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#faq2_2) and also [Setup script](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/Documentation.html#setup_script).

Comment: Something with PHP cause even this doesn't work: mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","XXX");

Comment: Maybe some permission problems. Look into log files or enable display PHP errors.

Comment: If you trying to connect via TCP connection, not via local socket, check that `mysqld` listens on that port (`netstat -an | grep 3306`). If it is not - remove `skip-networking` option from config file.